# Create an object within constructor of another object

Tags: powershell, acl, pipeline

I want to modify the ACL of a specific folder. To do this, I need to remove the inherited `FileSystemAccessRules`, and change them to `ReadAndExecute` permissions. To do this, I decided to use the `ModifyAccessRule()` method.

My problem is that I need to use the `ModifyAccessRule` method, and as part of the constructor, I need a `FileSystemAccessRule` object that would take the same input.

I am aware that this could be simply solved by not using a pipeline, but I am trying to keep it efficient and within one, hence why no external variables are being used (with the exception of the initial path).

```
Get-Item $folder_path |
%{$_.GetAccessControl()} |
%{$_.ModifyAccessRule(
    "Add",
    New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
         $_.Access.IdentityReference, 
         [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ReadAndExecute,
         [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit,
         [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None, 
         [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
         )
    )}
```

This is my code at the moment, but it does not work, due to `New-Object` not being executable inside a constructor. I have searched for a possible replacement, but have not found anything. As you can see, though, all the parts necessary for this new object are available.

Is there some type of format or method I could use to create this `FileSystemAccessRule` object within another object's constructor?

**PS:** As a bonus, can anyone confirm that `PropagationFlags` and `InheritanceFlags` are at the right values for the folder to not inherit parent permissions but propagate to children? ^-^

Comment: Simply enclose the new-object invocation in parens.

Comment: @wOxxOm woah, so it's that simple of a mistake, huh. ^-^